# string not printing

Tags: c, string

In this program I have to generate a random number and then if the number is 1 I have to store green in variable colour and if it is 0 I have to store red and then print the result

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main ()
{
    int rn;
    rn=Switch();
    Display(rn);
    return 0;
}
int Switch()
{
    int rn;
    srand(time(NULL));
    rn=rand()%2;
    return rn;
}
int Display(int rn)
{
    char colour[5];
    if (rn==1)
    {
        colour[5]="green";
    }
    else
    {
        colour[5]="red";
    }
    printf("Random number : %d\nColour : %c",rn,colour);
}
```

but when I run the program it prints the random number and it doesn't prints the colour.

Comment: you print a string into the fifth char of the array (which is not part of the array...). (Be careful with those nasal demons.) Also your array would be to small for the string.

Comment: You need to compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall` for gcc/clang), and then fix all of the warnings.

Comment: @KamiKaze how should i do it then??

Comment: compile with warnings enabled.

Answer (score 4):

```
colour[5]="green";
```

and

```
colour[5]="red";
```

leads to [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for multiple reasons (You are accessing the array `colour` outside of bounds and attempting to assign a string literal to a char).

You don't really need an array. Just use a pointer:

```
char *colour;
if (rn == 1) {
    colour="green";
} else {
    colour="red";
}
printf("Random number : %d\nColour : %s", rn, colour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change array declaration as `char colour[32] = {0};`

use `strcpy(colour, "green");` instead of `colour[5]="green";` similarly for red

use %s instead of %c while printing..

Comment: that would create another problem as you write more characters than there are slots in the array.

Comment: Yes, the array size is need to be increased in the case of green, right?

Comment: I would suggest that you write this in the answer to make it correct.